# git pull always opens a new commit window

Tags: git, github

I am facing some confusion with git, My git basics have messed up.

I was working on master branch and did few changes and did a git add+git commit
and after that I did a 
git pull, now I am getting confused as Whenever I do a git pull I am getting a new commit window.

Earlier whenever I did the above steps the commit message would never come up it would automatically merge with the remote origin.

Now whenever I do a git pull with the remote origin and new commit window pops up.

Something is messed but, i am not able to figure out.

Please, help.

Here's the git log, which looks weird to me.

The 1st commit shows up whenever I do a git pull.
Which should not happen unless I have messed up something.
Please, help me in understanding whats messed up.

```
commit e5dac0fbd72f17d87c9ec2090f29b603b399088f (HEAD -> master)
Merge: b44d245 f407e5b
Author: Abhi
Date:   Mon Apr 30 02:32:32 2018 -0700

    Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/networks/test_automation

commit b44d245400b72a994ff57f0ac2a5db7b75964266
Author: Abhi
Date:   Mon Apr 30 01:51:48 2018 -0700

    Test cases for the remote EP feature.

    Add test cases for pod traffic between same uplink, different uplink
    Add test cases for creating multiple EPG and assiging pods to EPG
    and checking the connectivity between them

commit f407e5bcae8a798a84e28d275432a324889523f8 (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: Ceridwen 
Date:   Fri Apr 20 16:40:31 2018 -0700

    Use acikubectl to write the cluster-report to a file

commit 8b0084c6ca9df913a05f6c910d923621032ea0d2
```

Comment: What happens if you do a second `git pull` immediately after your first?

Comment: Then it shows, Already upto date.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think the default `git log` in my opinion will not show you everything you might need to see to know what is going on here.

I would suggest using a tool like gitk or making a bash alias like:

`alias glog="git log --all --graph --pretty=oneline --decorate=short --abbrev-commit"`

And then using that to get a better insight in what a push/pull/merge/fetch actually does.

Remember, origin/master is the *remote* branch. The branch that anyone who does a `git clone` will see. `master` is a *local* branch. Only you will actually see what happens in your `master` branch. When you push `master` to `origin`, then `origin/master` will be updated with your commit.

However, `git push origin master` will only succeed if you already have the latest `origin/master` that has been pushed. In this case I think someone has pushed a commit to `origin/master` between your latest `git pull` and your `git commit`, meaning that your `master` was not in sync with `origin/master` when you made your commit. That would look like this:

`master  origin/master
|      /
B-----/
| 
A`

Here, `A` and `B` are commits that you both are seeing because both you and your colleague have done a `git pull` and fetched `A` and `B`. Your colleague has then pushed a new commit to `origin/master` which you have not fetched before you made your commit. Therefore, both your `master`, and `origin/master` are based directly on B.

When you do `git pull`, git will see this and attempt to merge the two commits. In your case it succeeded (hooray otherwise we would have a quite different question). The result of your `git pull` would then be:

`master
|    \
C  origin/master
|      /
B-----/
| 
A`

Here, `C` is your previous master. Since `C` and `origin/master` are not in sequence, git had to perform a merge and create a merge commit for this. That is what you see in your `git log`.

Why did you not see this in your previous `git pull`s? Well. If `master` and `origin/master` had not diverged, for example if your colleague had pushed something and you made a `git pull` before making your own commit, then your situation (before pull) would be something like this:

`origin/master
|
master
|
B
|
A`

In this situation, you do not need a merge and no merge commit would be created, because git would see that a "fast-forward" can be performed. A fast-forward just means git will move `master` forward without any merge, because the branches have not diverged. That might be what you have seen earlier.

In general, I think these things are easier to see if using better visualization tools (like gitk or the alias) and also I prefer doing `git fetch`, then look at it, then do `git merge origin/master`. Personally, I just think it makes it much easier to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for help.

Just incase if anybody wanted to know how I solved it then; I used git pull --rebase and it worked without creating a new commit.